# Link two Bootstrap Carousels on one page

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

I have got an interesting case where I want two carousels on one page and  one carousel to control another.
Please see  http://jsbin.com/bozenixiriko/1/

If I click on number , it should move to relevant video slide. And if I click on next in video carousel, it should move the number carousel.

Can you please suggest me how to achieve this functionality?

Comment: Can you post what code (JS, HTML) you have so far?

Comment: did you look at the `events` documentation for carousel?  there is an even that tells you when a carousel has changed

Comment: JME: Please check http://jsbin.com/bozenixiriko/1/edit

Comment: Here's a sample that is very similar to what I believe you want: http://www.bootply.com/jme11/u2HGq0HCpH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be making this a little more complex than it needs to be.  Your jsbin was expired, so I made a new fiddle.  In the process, I optimized some of your markup (see notes below).

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jme11/4aekwh3o/)

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container-fluid" id="slider">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div id="carousel-text">
                 <h3></h3>
            </div><!--/#carousel-text-->
        </div><!-- /.col-xs-12 #slider -->
        <div class="col-xs-12 hidden-xs carousel slide" data-type="multi" id="numberCarousel">
            <div class="carousel-inner row">
                <div class="item active"> 
                    <div class="col-xs-2">
                        <a data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0">
                            <span class="fa-stack fa-3x">
                                <i class="fa fa-circle-o fa-stack-2x"></i>
                                <i class="fa fa-stack-1x">1</i>
                            </span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item"> 
                    <div class="col-xs-2">
                        <a data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1">
                            <span class="fa-stack fa-3x">
                                <i class="fa fa-circle-o fa-stack-2x"></i>
                                <i class="fa fa-stack-1x">2</i>
                            </span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item"> 
                    <div class="col-xs-2">
                        <a data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2">
                            <span class="fa-stack fa-3x">
                                <i class="fa fa-circle-o fa-stack-2x"></i>
                                <i class="fa fa-stack-1x">3</i>
                            </span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item"> 
                    <div class="col-xs-2">
                        <a data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3">
                            <span class="fa-stack fa-3x">
                                <i class="fa fa-circle-o fa-stack-2x"></i>
                                <i class="fa fa-stack-1x">4</i>
                            </span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item"> 
                    <div class="col-xs-2">
                        <a data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="4">
                            <span class="fa-stack fa-3x">
                                <i class="fa fa-circle-o fa-stack-2x"></i>
                                <i class="fa fa-stack-1x">5</i>
                            </span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item"> 
                    <div class="col-xs-2">
                        <a data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="5">
                            <span class="fa-stack fa-3x">
                                <i class="fa fa-circle-o fa-stack-2x"></i>
                                <i class="fa fa-stack-1x">6</i>
                            </span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item"> 
                    <div class="col-xs-2">
                        <a data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="6">
                            <span class="fa-stack fa-3x">
                                <i class="fa fa-circle-o fa-stack-2x"></i>
                                <i class="fa fa-stack-1x">7</i>
                            </span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item"> 
                    <div class="col-xs-2">
                        <a data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="7">
                            <span class="fa-stack fa-3x">
                                <i class="fa fa-circle-o fa-stack-2x"></i>
                                <i class="fa fa-stack-1x">8</i>
                            </span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div><!-- /.carousel-inner.row -->
            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#numberCarousel" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="icon-prev"></span>
            </a>
            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#numberCarousel" data-slide="next">
                <span class="icon-next"></span>
            </a>
        </div><!-- /#numberCarousel -->
        <div class="col-xs-12" id="carousel-bounding-box">
            <div class="carousel slide" id="myCarousel">
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="active item" data-slide-title="Financial Derivatives - Lecture 01">
                        <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                            <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/KuJkFqBWpl0"></iframe>
                        </div>
                        <br />
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Crear apunte</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-right">Saltear a ejercicio</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item" data-slide-title="Financial Derivatives - Lecture 02">
                        <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                            <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/GXtxgzZkSZo"></iframe>
                        </div>
                        <br />
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Crear apunte</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-right">Saltear a ejercicio</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item" data-slide-title="Financial Derivatives - Lecture 03">
                        <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                            <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/aoUSUX2D5Is"></iframe>
                        </div>
                        <br />
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Crear apunte</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-right">Saltear a ejercicio</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item" data-slide-title="Financial Derivatives - Lecture 04">
                        <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                            <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/mgjBV9sWdIE"></iframe>
                        </div>
                        <br />
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Crear apunte</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-right">Saltear a ejercicio</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item" data-slide-title="Financial Derivatives - Lecture 05">
                        <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                            <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/orqUpKfSbrc"></iframe>
                        </div>
                        <br />
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Crear apunte</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-right">Saltear a ejercicio</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item" data-slide-title="Financial Derivatives - Lecture 06">
                        <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                            <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/joXhxg8MAyc"></iframe>
                        </div>
                        <br />
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Crear apunte</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-right">Saltear a ejercicio</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item" data-slide-title="Financial Derivatives - Lecture 07">
                        <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                            <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/2SSsaIt9LCk"></iframe>
                        </div>
                        <br />
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Crear apunte</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-right">Saltear a ejercicio</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item" data-slide-title="Financial Derivatives - Lecture 08">
                        <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                            <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/BJiEAU5OKiU"></iframe>
                        </div>
                        <br />
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Crear apunte</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-right">Saltear a ejercicio</button>
                    </div>
                </div><!-- /.carousel-inner -->
                <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="icon-prev"></span>
                </a>
                <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
                    <span class="icon-next"></span>
                </a>
            </div><!-- /#myCarousel -->
        </div><!-- /#carousel-bounding-box -->
    </div><!--/.row-->
</div><!--/.container-fluid-->
```

**CSS:**

```
#numberCarousel {
    padding: 40px;
}
#numberCarousel .carousel-inner {
    margin-left: 0;
}
#numberCarousel .item {
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#numberCarousel .carousel-inner > .next {
  left: 16.66666667%;
}
#numberCarousel .carousel-inner > .prev {
  left: -16.66666667%;
}
#numberCarousel .carousel-inner > .next.left,
#numberCarousel .carousel-inner > .prev.right {
  left: 0;
}
#numberCarousel .carousel-inner > .active.left {
  left: -16.66666667%;
}
#numberCarousel .carousel-inner > .active.right {
  left: 16.66666667%;
}
.carousel-control.left, .carousel-control.right {
    background-image: none;
}
.carousel-control {
    width: 10%;
}
#numberCarousel .carousel-control .icon-prev, #numberCarousel .carousel-control .icon-next {
    transform: translate(0, -50%);
}
```

**JS:**

```
// Initalize the "slide" title
$('#carousel-text>h3').text($('#myCarousel .active').data('slide-title')); 

// Initalize the carousels setting the interval to none
// This could also be done by just setting the data-interval to 0 in the markup
$('#myCarousel, #numberCarousel').carousel({
     interval: 0
});

// Make the thumbnail slider increment one at at time
$('.carousel[data-type="multi"] .item').each(function () {
     var next = $(this).next();
     if (!next.length) {
         next = $(this).siblings(':first');
     }
     next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));

     for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
         next = next.next();
         if (!next.length) {
             next = $(this).siblings(':first');
         }

         next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
     }
});

// When the carousel slides, auto update the text
// and move the corresponding number slide to be active
$('#myCarousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function () {
    activeslide = $(this).find('.active');
    $('#carousel-text>h3').text(activeslide.data('slide-title'));
    $('#numberCarousel').carousel(activeslide.index());
});
```

You had several unneeded nested divs that were making your markup harder to follow. Plus, just from the standpoint of simplification, the "text" or title is stored as a data attribute directly on the "slide".  It really makes no sense to store that information in your markup in a hidden div.  Including the title text as a data attribute is more semantic and natural; easier to code, maintain and test; and it saves having to go back to the DOM multiple times to update the text on your page.

The main change was to use the built in data attributes in the Bootstrap carousel to control sliding the main carousel when one of the items is clicked in the number carousel.   This is built in functionality.  It doesn't require any additional javascript, which means less dev, maintenance and testing for you (and a slightly smaller download for your users, even if it's only a few bytes).

Finally, to get the number carousel to synch when the next/prev buttons are clicked, since each carousel has the same number of items in the same order, you only have to pass the number carousel the index of the active slide in the main carousel.

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you so much. :) I have learned from your code. Is it possible that the number representing the active slide comes in the middle instead of at the beginning ?

Comment: I changed   `$('#numberCarousel').carousel(activeslide.index());` to   `$('#numberCarousel').carousel(activeslide.index()-2);` :)

Comment: It is possible, but currently there are 6 elements in the numberCarousel, so the middle would be position 3 or 4 in your mind?  and maybe the question is what is more intuitive to your users?  perhaps it would be better to add a different color to the active number?

Comment: Yup, that's would be the way to do it, except you'll need an if statement to take care of numbers less than 0.

Comment: Yes. For active slide, color also needs to be changed .